# Generic method that further constrains the class type parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I have a data structure with a `BisectLeft` method

```cs
public class MyStruct<T> where T: IComparable<T>
{
    public T BisectLeft(T item) {...}
}
```

I would like to add an overload of `BisectLeft` for a generic type `U` where `T: IComparable<U>`

```cs
    public T BisectLeft(T item) {...}

    public T BisectLeft<U>(U item) where T: IComparable<U> {...}
```

This doesn't compile because it cannot resolve the type `T`. I also cannot add `T` as `BisectLeft<T, U>` because `T` would be considered a duplicate of the type parameter of the class `MyStruct<T>`.

Is there anyway to achieve this without adding `U` as a type parameter of the class?

Comment: You can only add constraints on the type or method where you actually specified the generic type parameter? You cannot further restrict T on the method, since T was specified as a generic type parameter for the type owning the method. That class, and all its methods have to be usable for *all* T's that fit the constraints you added on the type. You will have to find another way of doing this. Perhaps an extension method would fit?

Comment: Try if this might work for you: `public static T BisectLeft<T, U>(this MyStruct<T> ms, U item) where T : IComparable<T>, IComparable<U> { ...` - This has to be defined in a static class nearby, however.

Comment: Thanks. That's a clever idea. Unfortunately `BisectLeft` accesses private data.

Answer (score 2):

You should specify your type parameter like `where T` either at the parent type, or at the methods. It won't work if you define it at both places.

In your case, you should do it only at the methods, like:

```
public class MyStruct
{
    public T BisectLeft<T>(T item)
        where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        return ...;
    }

    public T BisectLeft<T, U>(U item)
        where T : IComparable<U>
    {
        return ...;
    }
}
```